# Adding two list of lists with diffrent indext sizes

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix, union

Hi for example I have the List one with these headers:

```
edges1=['a', 'g', 'w', 'Q']
list1=[[0, 2, 0, 9], [2, 0, 15, 2], [0, 15, 0, 7], [9, 2, 7, 0]]
```

and

```
edges2=['a', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
list2=[[0, 0, 0, 12, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 5], [12, 2, 3, 0, 2], [0, 0, 5, 2, 0]]
```

as you can see these are graphs that has been saved in matrix shape. I need to add these together and whenever the is a common edges I should choose the lower value and put that in the final matrix.

The final answer should be like this:

```
    a:g:w:Q:front:Z
    0 2 0 9 12 0
    2 0 15 2 0 0
    0 15 0 7 2 0
    9 2 7 0 3 5
    12 0 2 3 0 2
    0 0 0 5 2 0
```

in the list form should looks like this:

```
  Final_list:[[0,2,0,9,12,0],[2,0,15,2,0,0],[0,15,0,7,2,0],[9,2,7,0,3,5],[12,0,2,3,0,2],[0,0,0,5,2,0]]
```

what methods should I use to get this output?

Comment: Can you tell me more about the problem here? what are the dimensions of the arrays or lists? it looks like you are trying to merge two totally different lists

Comment: Yes that is the problem I'm facing I have to very different lists that have some common numbers I have to add them together.

Comment: You want a transformation of the two list ? is this a problem given to you in class or you came up with this problem ? Any sources will help.

Answer (score 0):

Both list1 and list2 have different shapes/dimensions and to do any "additions" you would need to ensure the shapes are the same.

I would suggest use numpy to convert your 'lists' in to numpy arrays. From here you should be able to add extra rows and columns to match the shapes.

As for the 'addition' with the minimum value taken other than 0s. I would replace all 0s in your lists with a ridiculously large integer. You can then use numpy's minimum function to return an 'added' matrix. Just remember to replace all the ridiculously large integers in your resultant/added matrix with 0s again.

And you should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

Since the form edge 1 and 2 is a form of matrix, what you can do is create a new matrix using the length of a new union list of vertex for list 1 and list 2. So you have two same shape of new matrix 1 and matrix 2. Then you can compare them.